# How to fix "No compatible definition found for type 'Context'" from Koin lib?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I just started using Koin lib in an android (to replace Dagger 2) project which was prepared for tests. I have an issue with the android app context in module:

```
val M = module {
   val ctx = androidApplication() //here error
}
```

Koin is started in App class:

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin

class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin(this, listOf(M))
    }
}
```

I get log:

```
D/App: onCreate()
I/KOIN: [context] create
E/KOIN: [ERROR] - Error while resolving instance for class 'android.app.Application' - error: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No compatible definition found for type 'Application'. Check your module definition
```

and the app crashes. Did I miss something in the configuration of Koin? In the target project, I have a few modules which deeply depend on application context. And I don't want to use a global reference to this context.

Comment: I am facing this issue. Did the Accepted answer solve it for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try not to create a `val` for the `applicationAndroid()` context but use it directly inside the factory/single closure as a parameter for one of your dependencies.
What I'm doing in my project is something like:

```
val appModule = module(override = true) {
    factory<Navigator> { MyNavigator(androidApplication()) }
}
```

where the MyNavigator class is:

```
class MyNavigator(private val context: Context): Navigator {

    override fun goToDetail(detailId: String) {
        context.startActivity(DetailActivity.getIntent(context, detailId))
    }
}
```

---

p.s.: I did also some experiments with Koin 1.0.0 and I noticed that you can also write something like:

```
val appModule = module(override = true) {
    factory<Navigator> { MyNavigator(get()) }
}
```

That `get()` will retrieve the context for you even if there's no dependency in the graph for a Context instance; neither a factory nor a singleton. It might be that Koin does something behind the scenes. I tried to use it with different type of dependencies and it aways works.

Comment: I will check but see: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/190 author of Koin said that both ways are ok :)

Comment: I've seen that issue but in my case, the context declaration as a val doesn't work at all.

Comment: another solution: val ctx by lazy{ androidApplication() }

Answer (score 6):

Solution is easy but not so obvious.

Somehow Android Studio imports standalone startKoin function instead of specific android function.

So you had to replace

```
import org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.startKoin
```

To

```
import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin
```

in `Application` class

Do tell if this works or not.

Comment: nope :( Look at edited question. It's easy to reproduction: Just setup new project and configure Koin.

Comment: What if I want to do this from Java (not Kotlin)?

Comment: It worked for me, i had same error issue on my project, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had fix this problem to add all my `viewModels` to the `Koin module`.